# Stata adding variables complicated

Tags: variables, stata

I have a dataset in Stata on housing transactions. Now I have a dataset for which every row is a year in the holding period for each transaction. I am looking to research the probability of a house being sold in a certain year with a probit model. The dummy indicates whether the house was sold in that year or not, 1 being sold.

Now I want to add another variable to my data which contains the holding period of that specific transaction. This is (an example) of what I have now:

| dummy | year bought | current year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1620 | 1621 |
| 0 | 1620 | 1622 |
| 0 | 1620 | 1623 |
| 1 | 1620 | 1624 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1623 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1624 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1625 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1626 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1627 |
| 1 | 1622 | 1628 |

Then this is what I need it to become

| dummy | year bought | current year | holding period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1620 | 1621 | 4 |
| 0 | 1620 | 1622 | 4 |
| 0 | 1620 | 1623 | 4 |
| 1 | 1620 | 1624 | 4 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1623 | 6 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1624 | 6 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1625 | 6 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1626 | 6 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1627 | 6 |
| 1 | 1622 | 1628 | 6 |

Comment: Is every house in the data eventually sold? Is there a house id variable in the data too? So the holding period would just be the `max current year - min current year + 1` within each house id?

Comment: Yes every house is sold, and there is indeed a house id variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some kind of id variable for each house:

```
egen sold_year = max(current_year), by(house_id)
gen holding_period = sold_year - year_bought
```